# How does a backslash-newline combo affect the value of the C preprocessor's __LINE__ macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Per the C standard, collapsing multiple physical lines joined by a backslash-newline sequence is an earlier phase of translation than executing the preprocessor.

Assuming no complications due to an earlier `#line` directive, then, does the value of the `__LINE__` macro reflect the physical line number *before* such lines are spliced? That is what you'd find e.g. by manually inspecting the source or what a text editor would report the line # as, and would probably be the more useful alternative. Or does it reflect the line # subsequent to splicing, which presumably is what the preprocessor would actually see given the order of translation phases actually specified in the standard?

(And if I understand correctly--which I very well may not--the preprocessor would have no way of knowing whether a given line was the product of splicing or not.)

Comment: Why don't you write some simple code to try it?

Comment: I considered it, but I figured it wasn't worth the trouble because it wouldn't actually give me a useful answer.  As I see it, there are three possible answers: (1) the first way is unambiguously correct; (2) the second way is unambiguously correct; (3) the standard is ambiguous.  Whatever my particular compiler produced, it wouldn't actually rule out #3, so an answer/explanation grounded in the standard, either pointing out (and explaining, if it requires some complicated hermeneutics) the "correct" way or demonstrating the ambiguity if there is no one correct way, would be more helpful.

Comment: @kaylum: Trying it yourself shows how one compiler behaves in one circumstance. It does not explain what the requirements of the C standard are. And, as my answer shows, there are complications that would not necessarily be revealed by a simple experiment. Please stop suggesting that people should resolve questions about language standards by trying experiments. Experiments should be performed and are useful tools for aiding understanding, but they should not be promoted as dispositive or as acceptable alternatives to asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilers implement `__LINE__` by remembering physical line numbers in ways not specified by the C standard.

C 2018 6.10.8.1 1 tells us `__LINE__` is replaced by “The presumed line number (within the current source file) of the current source line (an integer constant).” This specification is vague and cannot be implemented in a useful way while adhering to the standard literally.

Consider this code:

```
#define Assert(test) do { if (!test) printf("Assertion on line %d failed.\n", __LINE__); } while (0)

... Many lines of code follow, including some with line splicing.

    Assert(condition);

... Many lines of code.
```

To be useful, this code must print the physical line number on which the `Assert` is used. It needs to be the physical line number so that the user can locate the line in a text editor, and it needs to be the line on which the `Assert` macro is replaced, not defined, because that is where the problem is detected. Both GCC and Clang do this.

However, this requires that the physical line number from **before** line splicing be provided during macro replacement, which occurs **after** line splicing. In C 2018 5.1.1.2 1, the standard specifies a translation model in which:

- in phase 2, “Each instance of a backslash character () followed immediately by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines,” and,
- in phase 3, “The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and white-space characters,” including new-line characters but not ones deleted in phase 2, and,
- in phase 4, macro invocations are expanded.

So, if a compiler replaces a `__LINE__` macro in phase 4 and literally has only the preprocessing tokens and remaining white-space characters, it cannot know the physical line number to provide.

Therefore, a compiler cannot be implemented literally following the standard’s model of translation. To be useful, it must associate a physical line number with each preprocessing token that could be a macro name. Whenever a macro is replaced, it must propagate the associated physical line number. Then, when a `__LINE__` token is finally replaced, the compiler will have the associated physical line number to replace it with.

Comment: This is exactly what I was wondering about, particularly re: the implications of the ordering of translation phases per the standard.  Thank you!

Comment: Re: "a compiler cannot be implemented literally following the standard’s model of translation": indeed. I guess that from `__LINE__` people expect "number of physical source line" (and not "number of logical source line"). However, even if "it must associate a physical line number with each preprocessing token", the `__LINE__` values can be [different](https://godbolt.org/z/W8ab47e6f).

Answer (score 1):

A multiline macro joined by newlines gets translated into a single line of code, so it gives you the line that the macro appeared on.

For example, given the following code:

```
#define TEST do {\
    printf("line1=%d\n" __LINE__);\
    printf("line2=%d\n" __LINE__);\
    printf("line3=%d\n" __LINE__);\
} while (0)

int main(void)
{
    TEST;
    return 0;
}
```

Passing it through the preprocessor in gcc gives you this:

```
# 1 "x1.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "x1.c"






int main(void)
{
    do { printf("line1=%d\n" 9); printf("line2=%d\n" 9); printf("line3=%d\n" 9);} while (0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answers about a “A multiline macro joined by newlines”. But the question did not ask about a multiline macro. This does not answer the question because the `__LINE__` macros used here are inside a macro definition, so they manifest in the source where the macro is expanded. When the `__LINE__` macro appears by itself, not as part of some other macro definition, GCC and Clang replace it with the number of the physical line it appears on, disregarding line splicing.